# How to create a non-resizable and 100% screen (not full screen) BrowserWindow

Tags: electron

I want my main window to be 100% of screen not full screen as well as not resizable.

```
const electron = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');

const{app, BrowserWindow} = electron;

let mainWindow;

app.on('ready', function(){
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({resizable:false,height:800,width:1535});
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname,"index.html"),
        protocol: 'file',
        slashes:true
    }));

    mainWindow.on('closed',function(){
        app.quit();
    });
});
```

Comment: What does "100% of screen not full screen" mean?

Comment: Try to set the size to [`screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/screen.md#screengetprimarydisplay) or such

Comment: i mean maximized not full screen

Answer (score 5):

Your display's `workAreaSize` should be equal to maximized window size, as I mentioned in comment

```
const electron = require('electron')
const {app, BrowserWindow} = electron

app.on('ready', () => {
  const display = electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay()
  const maxiSize = display.workAreaSize
  new BrowserWindow({
    resizable: false,
    height: maxiSize.height,
    width: maxiSize.width
  })
})
```